# Using a Web Lock within a WebView to stop the tab being frozen

Tags: android, .net, webview, signalr, maui

I am using a WebView within a Maui app to display my website on an Android device.
The website uses the SignalR Javascript library on the client side to maintain a SignalR connection with the server (as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)).

There is an acknowledged problem with using the SignalR Javascript library, that browsers will freeze inactive tabs which then breaks the SignalR connection. Microsoft provide a workaround [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#bsleep) with one of the options being to hold a weblock within the tab, as browsers will not freeze a tab that is holding a weblock.

My problem is that I have added a weblock to the tab (which I have verified through console output as being held), but even so the tab is still being frozen (verified by the log message on the freeze event from the signalr library).
I'm wondering whether WebView is somehow different in this aspect than a regular browser tab?

Comment: Web Locks are experimental. The conditional check confirms that the browser supports Web Locks.

Comment: Absolutely @GuangyuBai-MSFT. The issue here is that the browser clearly supports WebLocks, but is still freezing the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this document](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/chrome/browser/performance_manager/docs/freezing_opt_out_opt_in.md#page-freezing-opt_in-and-opt_out) which appears to state that opt-in/opt-out of freezing is not enabled on mobile. There is no date on the document so it's difficult to know if it is still current.